# How to send multiple commands in one sesssion but save outputs separately

Tags: go, session, ssh, output

My code is supposed to SSH to a remote-host (let’s say Routers) and run multiple commands on the remote-host and return the outputs.

The code attached is simplified and has three parts:

- `Main` function: Reads list of commands and then by using the `ExecCommands` function dials/ssh to a remote-host to execute the commands.
- `ExecCommands` function takes the remote-host IP, list of commands and SSH `ClientConfig` that is used for SSH. Then it dials to the IP and run the commands one-by-one. At the end, returns the output of all commands in only one string
- `InsecureClientConfig` function that actually doesn’t do much except creating a SSH `ClientConfig` which is used for `ExecCommands` function

This program works well when I just want to apply some commands or config and save the wholes result. I mean `ExecCommands` takes the bunch of commands, push all of them to the remote-host and returns (or saves) the whole output of applied commands in one string as output.

**Problem:**

- I cannot process the output of each command individually. For example, assume that I apply CMD1, CMD2, CMD3, … to the remote-host#1 by using ExecCommands function. Since it gives me back the whole output in one string, it is hard to find which output belongs to which CMD

**Goal:**

- Modify or re-design `ExecCommands` function to the way that it provides separate output for each command it applies. It means if for `remote-host#1` it applies 10 commands, I should have 10 separate strings as output.

**Conditions/Restrictions:**

- I can **not** create any extra session for commands and must apply all commands in the first SSH session I created, i.e. cannot create multiple Sessions and use `Run`, `Shell`, `Output`, `Start` function in SSH package
- No re-authentication is allowed. For example, I have only a single one-time-password that can be used for all remote-hosts.
- Remote hosts don't support "echo" like commands similar to what you have in Linux
- The remote-hosts dont’s support any type of APIs

**Points:**

- Main focus is the function `ExecCommands`. I put a simplified version of the whole code to give an idea
- I am using `stdout, err := session.StdoutPipe()` to run multiple commands which means -as  pipe - it's Reader only is possible to be read when the job is done.
- An option is to use `Session.Stdout` and `Session.Stdin` inside of the for loop in `ExecCommands` function. Tried but was not successful.

**Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main() {

    // List of the commands should be sent to the devices
    listCMDs := []string{
        "set cli op-command-xml-output on",
        "test routing fib-lookup virtual-router default ip 1.1.1.1",
        "test routing fib-lookup virtual-router default ip 2.2.2.2",
        "show interface ethernet1/1",
        "show interface ethernet1/2",
        "test security-policy-match protocol 6 source 1.1.1.1 destination 2.2.2.2 destination-port 443 from ZONE1 to ZONE2",
        "test security-policy-match protocol 6 source 10.0.0.1 destination 10.0.2.1 destination-port 443 from ZONE1 to ZONE2",
        "exit",
    }

    sshconfig := InsecureClientConfig("admin", "admin")

    s, err := ExecCommands("192.168.1.250", listCMDs, sshconfig)
    fmt.Println(s, err)
}

// ExecCommands ...
func ExecCommands(ipAddr string, commands []string, sshconfig *ssh.ClientConfig) (string, error) {

    // Gets IP, credentials and config/commands, SSH Config (Timeout, Ciphers, ...) and returns
    // output of the device as "string" and an error. If error == nil, means program was able to SSH with no issue

    // Creating outerr as Output Error.
    outerr := errors.New("nil")
    outerr = nil

    // Creating Output as String
    var outputStr string

    // Dial to the remote-host
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", ipAddr+":22", sshconfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    // Create sesssion
    session, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()

    // StdinPipee() returns a pipe that will be connected to the remote command's standard input when the command starts.
    // StdoutPipe() returns a pipe that will be connected to the remote command's standard output when the command starts.
    stdin, err := session.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    stdout, err := session.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Start remote shell
    err = session.Shell()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Send the commands to the remotehost one by one.
    for _, cmd := range commands {
        _, err := stdin.Write([]byte(cmd + "\n"))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }

    // Wait for session to finish
    err = session.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    strByte, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(stdout)
    outputStr = string(strByte)

    return outputStr, outerr
}

// InsecureClientConfig ...
func InsecureClientConfig(userStr, passStr string) *ssh.ClientConfig {

    SSHconfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User:    userStr,
        Timeout: 5 * time.Second,
        Auth:    []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.Password(passStr)},

        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
        Config: ssh.Config{
            Ciphers: []string{"aes128-ctr", "aes192-ctr", "aes256-ctr", "aes128-cbc", "aes192-cbc",
                "aes256-cbc", "3des-cbc", "des-cbc"},
            KeyExchanges: []string{"diffie-hellman-group1-sha1",
                "diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1",
                "diffie-hellman-group14-sha1"},
        },
    }
    return SSHconfig
}
```

Comment: IIRC, a new session will not need reauthentication. Only dial needs authentication.

Comment: If you must execute these in a single shell, you are limited by what that shell can do. There's nothing ssh or Go can do to fix the output of that remote shell. Can you echo some delimiter to the output stream separate each command's output?

Comment: @Burak Serdar . Thanks for the quick response. would you mind exemplifying for me please? The last time I tried wasn't successful

Comment: @JimB. Thanks to you too for the quick response. I didn't follow exactly what you mean

Comment: A session is meant to execute one command. You can create a session, run a command, get the response, and create another session for the next one. What error did you get? The only example I can provide is in this project I wrote a while ago, which actually does what you need: ssh into many hosts and do things on them: https://github.com/bserdar/watermelon/blob/master/server/backends/remotelinux/rmtlinhost.go (it is pretty big, but it creates one connection and multiple sessions)

Comment: @Burak Serdar This is what I understand: `session1, err := client.NewSession()` then `session1.Shell()` then `session1.Output("COMMAND")` finally `session1.Wait()`

And same for session2, session3 

If this is the case, after running `session1.Output` I get this `Stdout already set`

Comment: Also I just tried this: `session1, err := client.NewSession()` then `session1.Run("COMMAND")` and save the output in a Buffer `var b1 bytes.Buffer` and `session1.Stdout = &b1` And same for session2, session3 but no luck :(

Comment: @Deibedyn: what part don't you understand? You're interacting with a single shell, and therefore only have a single output stream. If you need to separate the output of each command, can you delimit the output from within the shell?

Comment: @JimB Thanks for trying to help. Understood. Not sure I can put any character or anything else to delimit the output. The point is many commands have similar output (what process is running, what is the route to this IP, etc.) 
Tried to use different session [https://play.golang.org/p/HYbLcrAlNz6] and here [https://play.golang.org/p/c3anBjdKM9c] by using `Run` and `Output` command. No luck

Comment: @mh-cbon Thanks for your comment. The point is almost none of the network devices - as exampled in my question, doesn't support echo

Answer (score 0):

This works properly:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main() {

    // List of the commands should be sent to the devices
    listCMDs := []string{
        "set cli op-command-xml-output on\n",
        "test routing fib-lookup virtual-router default ip 1.1.1.1\n",
        "test routing fib-lookup virtual-router default ip 2.2.2.2\n",
        "show interface ethernet1/1\n",
        "show interface ethernet1/2\n",
        "test security-policy-match protocol 6 source 1.1.1.1 destination 2.2.2.2 destination-port 443 from ZONE1 to ZONE2\n",
        "test security-policy-match protocol 6 source 10.0.0.1 destination 10.0.2.1 destination-port 443 from ZONE1 to ZONE2\n",
        "exit",
    }

    sshconfig := InsecureClientConfig("admin", "Ghazanfar1!")

    s, _ := ExecCommands("192.168.1.249", listCMDs, sshconfig)

    for _, item := range s {
        fmt.Println(item)
        fmt.Println("-------------------------------")
    }
}

// ExecCommands ...
func ExecCommands(ipAddr string, commands []string, sshconfig *ssh.ClientConfig) ([]string, error) {

    // Gets IP, credentials and config/commands, SSH Config (Timeout, Ciphers, ...) and returns
    // output of the device as "string" and an error. If error == nil, means program was able to SSH with no issue

    // Creating outerr as Output Error.
    outerr := errors.New("nil")
    outerr = nil

    // Creating Output as String
    var outputStr []string
    var strTmp string

    // Dial to the remote-host
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", ipAddr+":22", sshconfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    // Create sesssion
    session, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()

    // StdinPipee() returns a pipe that will be connected to the remote command's standard input when the command starts.
    // StdoutPipe() returns a pipe that will be connected to the remote command's standard output when the command starts.
    stdin, err := session.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    stdout, err := session.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Start remote shell
    err = session.Shell()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    stdinLines := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            stdinLines <- scanner.Text()
        }
        if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
            log.Printf("scanner failed: %v", err)
        }
        close(stdinLines)
    }()

    // Send the commands to the remotehost one by one.
    for i, cmd := range commands {
        _, err := stdin.Write([]byte(cmd + "\n"))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        if i == len(commands)-1 {
            _ = stdin.Close() // send eof
        }

        // wait for command to complete
        // we'll assume the moment we've gone 1 secs w/o any output that our command is done
        timer := time.NewTimer(0)
    InputLoop:
        for {
            timer.Reset(time.Second)
            select {
            case line, ok := <-stdinLines:
                if !ok {
                    log.Println("Finished processing")
                    break InputLoop
                }
                strTmp += line
                strTmp += "\n"
            case <-timer.C:
                break InputLoop
            }
        }
        outputStr = append(outputStr, strTmp)
        //log.Printf("Finished processing %v\n", cmd)
        strTmp = ""
    }

    // Wait for session to finish
    err = session.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return outputStr, outerr
}

// InsecureClientConfig ...
func InsecureClientConfig(userStr, passStr string) *ssh.ClientConfig {

    SSHconfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User:    userStr,
        Timeout: 5 * time.Second,
        Auth:    []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.Password(passStr)},

        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
        Config: ssh.Config{
            Ciphers: []string{"aes128-ctr", "aes192-ctr", "aes256-ctr", "aes128-cbc", "aes192-cbc",
                "aes256-cbc", "3des-cbc", "des-cbc"},
            KeyExchanges: []string{"diffie-hellman-group1-sha1",
                "diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1",
                "diffie-hellman-group14-sha1"},
        },
    }
    return SSHconfig
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have limited number of commands to run on special hardwares and you know the pattern of the each command's output, you may use `strings.Split` or `regexp` to split the output.
And if you do not have `echo` command, but know any command with fast response with unique output pattern, then you may replace it with `echo` command in the following example (number 2).

---

Since a session only accepts **one call** to `Run`, `Start`, `Shell`, `Output`, or `CombinedOutput`, and you do **not** want to start a new session per command:

The key is to use a `strings.Builder` and empty it using `sb.Reset()` befor sending the command, and using `io.Copy` to copy **concurrently**  the session's stdout into `strings.Builder` (assuming you do **not** need session's stderr):

```
sb := new(strings.Builder)
go io.Copy(sb, stdout)
```

1. This works if you know how much to wait for each command (tested):

```
sb := new(strings.Builder)
go io.Copy(sb, stdout)

commands := []string{"uname -a", "sleep 1", "pwd", "whoami", "exit"}
wait := []time.Duration{10, 1200, 20, 10, 10} // * time.Millisecond
ans := []string{}

time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond) // wait for the ssh greetings

// Send the commands to the remotehost one by one.
for i, cmd := range commands {
    sb.Reset()
    fmt.Println("*** command:\t", cmd)
    _, err := stdin.Write([]byte(cmd + "\n"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    time.Sleep(wait[i] * time.Millisecond) // wait for the command to finish
    s := sb.String()
    fmt.Println("*** response:\t", s)
    ans = append(ans, s)
}
```

---

2. Using string delimiter and `strings.Split` (Note: You may replace `echo` with any fast command with known output pattern):

```
sb := new(strings.Builder)
go io.Copy(sb, stdout)
commands := []string{"uname -a", "sleep 1", "pwd", "whoami"}
delim := "********--------========12345678"
for _, cmd := range commands {
    _, err = stdin.Write([]byte("echo " + delim + "\n"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    _, err := stdin.Write([]byte(cmd + "\n"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
_, err = stdin.Write([]byte("exit\n"))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
err = session.Wait() // Wait for session to exit
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
ans := strings.Split(sb.String(), delim)
ans = ans[1:] // remove ssh greetings
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this out: https://github.com/yahoo/vssh
You can set sessions to how many commands you need to run concurrently then send each command to remote host through run method and get the result individually!

Comment: Thanks @Mehrdad for that.. Are you sure it supports multiple commands per session? From the doc, the method `run` looks like gets only one command?

Comment: it creates one connection then for each run it creates a session. (you need to set the max sessions)

Comment: Thanks. will try and let you know what the outcome is